# How do I make a global keyboard listener on C++? (Mac OSX)

Tags: c++, curses

I want to get global keyboard input for an application I am making which runs in the background.

Expected results include being able to print the character in the console when I press a keyboard key outside of the window that the application is running on (in this case, Terminal).

I have tries using `ncurses.h` and `curses.h` but they seem to have symbols which are not recognised by Xcode:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _main in main.o

  "_wgetch", referenced from:
      _main in main.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#include <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << getch();
    
}
```

Can anyone suggest a library contained in the OS X files that can help me? Or if possible, can anybody help me with figuring out how to get past the errors above?

**edit**

I am a second-time poster (my first one went wrong), please point out if I can improve this or if I should delete this question altogether.

Comment: try to have a look at the library SDL2: https://www.libsdl.org/

Comment: How do I include it?

Comment: try to look for "Documentation", "tutorial", "examples" and so on. Google will be your best colleague!

Comment: You need to link with the library that contains the function definitions – the headers only declare them. But neither of those (nor SDL2, I believe) will help you make a keylogger.

Comment: I am using it to bind two keys (\ and = together) to an auto clicker I made a while back, so yes if you call that key logging, but no otherwise. Should I post the auto clicker code here in the comments section too?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specifically link the library, i.e.:

```
c++ -oprogname progname.cpp -lcurses
```

However, this will only resolve the "Undefined symbols" errors; it won't get you a "global keyboard listener".